# Which episodes did the Furlings sketch in the "200" episode of Stargate SG-1 pull stock footage from?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the *Stargate SG-1* episode "200", there is a sketch showing SG-1 meeting the Furlings (which ends with Sam saying "Well that never happened!").

There are a few scenes that look like they were reused from previous seasons, like the Deathgliders getting shot up (one of the season opening credits used it). I also suspect that Teal'c saying "we led them straight here" was stock footage since he is without hair in that clip, but "200" was a Season 10 episode and he was on his third season with hair.

Which episodes did this sketch pull stock footage from?

Comment: I'm not sure if [identify-this-episode] would be appropriate for this question or not.

Answer (score 1):

[This Video](https://youtu.be/UVT-yLGyGJE?t=467) suggests that those scenes were shot especially for the 200th episode, to match the fans "ewok-style furry creatures" idea (see the Ewok-style village as well as the Koala style bodysuits).
While Gateworld (producers of the video) are fans rather than authoritative sources, they have been active for over a decade and the video is a full investigation into the Furlings, including re-watching all episodes to find mentions so they definitely would have come across those clips if they had existed anywhere else.

Comment: Where does that video state that? I didn't notice it.

Comment: 8:30 "..... never happened.  It was a fun nod from the Show's writers to the fans ....."

Comment: How does that imply "those scenes were shot especially for the 200th episode", which is what this question is about?

Comment: "Never happened" = did not previously exist.  Check the final sentence - if the clips had come from any other episode Gateworld would have found them & said so.

Comment: I always thought it was pretty obvious that it was a comedy sketch made up for the 200th show and made for fun. I never thought beyond that because there was nothing to think about other than enjoy the joke.